# Change parent page url from an iFrame works in IE but not in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page with an iFrame in it. I want to change the url of the parent.
Currently, I'm using this code:

```
window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href + '?myParam=myValue'
```

and it works in IE 10, but not in Firefox or Chrome.
On Firefox I get the following error:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'href'

The page and iFrame share host, but are on different ports, so according to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) it won't not work.
My question is: why does it work in IE and what to do to make it work in other browsers?

**Edit:** The following works just fine:

```
window.parent.location.href = 'addressGoesHere.com?myParam=myValue';
```

in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Try this</strike>

```
window.parent.location='?myParam=myValue';
```

I tried and found that: you can't access location of documents from different directly (getting it's value) or indirectly (by setting it's location relative - it will become relative to page setting location - the only exception is setting hash (#123)).

So actual answer:

it works in IE because it doesn't meets the standarts

and second part - there is absolutely no way. You should try different methods of communicating - like using cross-domain postmessage ( http://html5demos.com/postmessage2 ) or using other cross-domain communication methods like http://easyxdm.net/wp

Comment: I got the following error: Error: Permission denied to access property 'valueOf'

Comment: I tried and found that: you can't access location of documents from different directly (getting it's value) or indirectly (by setting it's location relative - it will become relative to page **setting** location - the only exception is setting hash (#123)). So actual answer: it works in IE because it doesn't meets the standarts, and second part - there is absolutely no way. You should try different methods of communicating - like using cross-domain postmessage ( http://html5demos.com/postmessage2 ) or using other cross-domain communication methods like http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with the postMessage